# doxygen how to include description when referencing an entity

Tags: doxygen

in some file there is a function

```
///some description of the function foo.
void foo();
```

in a page in the documentation

```
\ref foo()
```

I get a link to foo() but is there a way to include the description

```
"///some description of the function foo."
```

along with the link.

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\ref` command has as second argument the possibility to show a text but this text has to be between quotes and will be shown as link text. This means though that you have to type the text again.

When we assume that the requested text us the brief description of the function we could do something like:

```
/// \ref foo() \copybrief foo()
```

A full example:

```
/// \file
///
/// \ref foo()
///
/// \ref foo() \copybrief foo()
///
/// \ref bar()
///
/// \ref bar() "some description of the function bar."
///
/// \ref bar() \copybrief bar()

/// some description of the function foo.
void foo();

/// \brief some description of the function bar.
void bar();
```

Resulting in:

[image]

When the requested text is not the brief description, the user probably accomplish something with the commands like `\copydetails` / `\copydoc` or `\snippet{doc}`.