# Doxygen link generation with documentation text text

Tags: c, doxygen

i can link to the enum documentation with the # symbol

in the generated html it links to the the enum

when put the mouse over the link there is a tooltip with the text of the documentation

how can i get the text of the documentation ?

when i write somewhere #MY_ENUM i get a link but how can i get the text and not only a tooltip

for example in enum.h i write this

```
/**
 * @file enums.h
 */

typedef enum{
    MY_ENUM     = 0x1, ///< Some text
}SOME_ENUM;
```

and in an other_header.h i write this

```
/**
 * @file other_header.h
 */

/**
 * Funktion Description
 *
 * Values for SOME_ENUM can be<br>
 * #MY_ENUM
 */
int some_function( SOME_ENUM parameter );
```

in the html documentation for some_function a link to MY_ENUM is generated
but i whould like to have the Text 'Some text' after the link

or is it possible to insert the hole SOME_ENUM table there ?

Comment: To me it is unclear what exactly does not work. Your code does not contain any Doxygen comment that contains `#`. I'm not even sure if Doxygen would generate documentation for `MY_ENUM` when `SOME_ENUM` is not documented.  Please [edit] your question and create a [mre].

Comment: it work if MY_ENUM is not documentated

Answer (score 0):

When I interpret the question you would like to see in the output something like:

[image]

did you try:

```
#MY_ENUM \copybrief MY_ENUM
```

as this will give the result of the image.

See also my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889048/1657886 to a similar question.